# How to compare specific Values of tuples with an AVG-value in SQL over two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, average

I am searching for a query, where it's possible to "join" an AVG-value with the specific values of all tuples.

So I have the following Data (The topic is a Dataset about Companies):

table1:
ID Name Country Class

table2:
ID Value1 Value2

I managed to get the AVG-value of Value1/Value2 for the specific Country and Class of a Company.
Now I am trying to show the amount of Companies for a Country/Class which are in the 5% value range of the AVG-value of their class. 
I tried all the possibilities i could imaginne. The Problem I am struggling with is the fact, that it's not possible to give back more than one value in a nested query.

Can anyone give me an approach for solving this problem?

Comment: Plz provide some sample data and expected O/P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need something like this:

```
with data as (
  select cname, country, class, value1/value2 vv
      , avg(value1/value2) over (partition by country, class) av
    from vals join companies using (id) )
select country, class, count(case when vv/av < 0.2 then 1 end) cnt
  from data group by country, class
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60212/1)

How it works? In first step for each id we gather information about average (value1/value2) partitioned by country and class.
This is column `av` in subquery `data`, analytic function `avg()` is used for calculations. The output of this subquery is:

```
CNAME      COUNTRY    CLASS         VV         AV
---------- ---------- ----- ---------- ----------
GHI        China      A             30         30
ABC        Russia     A              5       32,5
JKL        Russia     A             60       32,5
DEF        Russia     B              3          3
```

Next we only need to group data by country and class and attach information about amount of companies meeting your criteria.
So output of the full query is (I used 20%, change condition `vv/av < 0.2` to anything you need):

```
COUNTRY    CLASS        CNT
---------- ----- ----------
Russia     A              1
China      A              0
Russia     B              0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `AVG()` as a window (analytic) function:

```
SELECT id, name, country, class, company_value FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.country, t1.class, t2.value1/t2.value2 AS company_value
         , AVG(t2.value1/t2.value2) OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.country, t1.class ) AS avg_value
      FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id
) WHERE company_value BETWEEN avg_value * 0.95 AND avg_value * 1.05;
```

In the above query I am using `0.95` and `1.05` for `1 - 0.05` and `1 + 0.05` respectively (within 5%). To get the count simply use the above as a subquery (or CTE if you're more comfortable with that):

```
SELECT country, class, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT id, name, country, class, company_value FROM (
        SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.country, t1.class, t2.value1/t2.value2 AS company_value
             , AVG(t2.value1/t2.value2) OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.country, t1.class ) AS avg_value
          FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
            ON t1.id = t2.id
    ) WHERE company_value BETWEEN avg_value * 0.95 AND avg_value * 1.05
);
```